# How to provide the definition of a friend operator in a nested class of a template class?

Tags: c++

This works:

```
template<class Tim>
struct Bob
{
    struct Dave
    {
        Tim t{};
        friend bool operator < (const Dave& a, const Dave& b)
        {
            return a.t < b.t;
        }
    } d;
};
```

This does not work:

```
template<class Tim>
struct Bob
{
    struct Dave
    {
        Tim t{};
        friend bool operator < (const Dave& a, const Dave& b);
    } d;
};

template<class Tim>
bool operator < (const typename Bob<Tim>::Dave& a, const typename Bob<Tim>::Dave& b)
{
    return a.t < b.t;
}
```

When I try to use it in a map for example, I get linker errors:

```
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl operator<(struct Bob<int>::Dave const &,struct Bob<int>::Dave const &)" (??M@YA_NABUDave@?$Bob@H@@0@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall std::less<struct Bob<int>::Dave>::operator()(struct Bob<int>::Dave const &,struct Bob<int>::Dave const &)const " (??R?$less@UDave@?$Bob@H@@@std@@QBE_NABUDave@?$Bob@H@@0@Z)
```

.

```
int main()
{
    std::map<Bob<int>::Dave, int> v;
    v[{}];
}
```

How can I define this operator correctly *outside* the class?

Comment: If you turn on warnings, you get: `warning: friend declaration 'bool operator<(const Bob<Tim>::Dave&, const Bob<Tim>::Dave&)' declares a non-template function`(and a hint what to do about it) - so the friend `operator<` you declare, and the `template<...> operator<` you define further down are not the same thing.

Comment: @melak47 VS2015 warning level 4, I do not get any warning.

Comment: Sorry, see gcc's output: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb58214d285f031f

Comment: @melak47 I don't understand how to follow the hint.

Comment: @NeilKirk The hint is also in https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends.

Comment: @melak47 How can I forward declare the nested class `Dave` as required by that solution?

Comment: @NeilKirk, no way with forward declarations: https://ideone.com/r6QFSS . Works well only when the operator is defined inside class declaration or when the operator is member.

Answer (score 4):

You would normally do such a thing by forward-declaring the template class and the friend function and then providing a specialization within the class definition. However, in this case it is not as easy - having a dependent type puts the `Tim` class in a non-deduced context, so the deduction will fail. However, there's a way around it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>

template<class T>
struct Bob;

template<typename T, typename>
bool operator < (const T& a, const T& b);

struct DaveTag {};

template<class Tim>
struct Bob
{
    struct Dave : DaveTag
    {
        Tim t{};


        friend bool operator < <Bob<Tim>::Dave, void>(const typename Bob<Tim>::Dave& a, const typename Bob<Tim>::Dave& b);
    } d;
};

template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<DaveTag, T>::value>::type>
bool operator < (const T& a, const T& b)
{
    return a.t < b.t;
}

struct X {
    double t;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<Bob<int>::Dave, int> v;
    v[{}];

    // This won't work
    // X x, y;
    //bool b = x < y;

}
```

Basically, what I've done here is let the compiler deduce the full `Bob<Tim>::Dave` as the template parameter for `operator<`. However, clearly a simple definition would allow for any types to be deduced for `T` potentially leading to some difficult-to-understand problems. To avoid it I added a small tag class `DaveTag` which allows to prevent instantiations of our very generic `operator<` for anything but `Dave`.

Comment: I applaud your effort here!

Comment: @NeilKirk No problem! I was having fun too :)

Comment: I came up with a workaround which is good enough for my situation and a bit simpler :)

Comment: @NeilKirk Yeah, I thought there would be an easier way. That's C++ in a nutshell :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a satisfactory workaround. I didn't want to implement the operator in the class for various reasons (definitions not available at that point, some explicit template instantiation going on here) but I can live with the following:

```
struct Bob
{
    struct Dave
    {
        Tim t{};

        static bool LessThan(const Dave& a, const Dave& b);

        friend bool operator < (const Dave& a, const Dave& b)
        {
            return LessThan(a, b);
        }
    } d;
};
```

Now the static function `LessThan` can be implemented out of the class in the normal way.